# how to load Data from multiple child and show in same tableView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Right now my tableview shows some data from a child in Firebase. Depending on which id is selected it only shows the data or comments regarding to this id.
I want to also show in the same tableView data from other id. How can I do that?

With this I get the data from a child with specific place ID.

```
    func datenBankAbfrage () {
        let placeIdFromSearch = ViewController.placeidUebertragen
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(placeIdFromSearch)")
        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "userTime").queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.table.removeAll()
                
                for video in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let Object = video.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    
                    let userName = Object?["userName"]
                    let userGroup = Object?["userGroup"]
                    let userComment = Object?["userComment"]
                    let userTime = Object?["userTime"]
                    let userLikes = Object?["userLikes"]
                    let commentId = Object?["commentId"]
                    ViewComments.commentIDNew = commentId as! String
                    
                    let video = importComment(userName: userName as! String, userGroup: userGroup as! String, userComment: userComment as! String, userTime: userTime as! Int, userLikes: userLikes as! Int, commentId: commentId as! String)
                    self.table.insert(video, at: 0)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

So I am searching somethings like

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("placeID/\(placeIdFromSearch) & this child and that child ")
```

Comment: The question is vague. You've stated your tableView displays data from an id; in  your code is that `placeID` here -> `child("placeID/\(placeIdFromSearch)")`. But then you want to display data from *other id* - what is *other id*? Where is that in your code? @frankvanpuffelen answer is good but it sounds like another option is to denormalize the data. Can you clarify the question? Also, capital letters are reserved for Class, Struct and Enum names. Vars should always start with lower case. e.g. MyClass or MyStruct and myVar. This `ViewComments` is unclear as it looks like a class property.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a subset of the child nodes of a path is with a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data), so if the nodes either share a common property (`queryEqualToValue(...)`) or if they are within a contiguous range (`queryStartingAtValue`/`queryEndingAtValue`).

Beyond that it is not possible to load a subset of child nodes with an OR like condition. This means that you will have to load each branch with a separate read operation, and then merge the data together in your application code. This is not nearly as slow as you may expect, since Firebase [pipelines the requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) together over the same connection.